# Is BPT framework supports Descriptive programming?

Tags: qtp, sapui5, hp-uft, siebel

Can we use Descriptive programing using BPT framework. we have prepared almost 70 components for Siebel open UI. when I try to run the BPT test case , it is not working. 
Just wanted to confirm whether BPT framework supports Descriptive programming or not.

Is there any way so that it can support if not getting supported.

Comment: When you say not working, what are you referring to? Can you give an error message screenshot or description in your write up?

Comment: @dmcgill50 : I have created an object  for Browser as oBrowse = Description.create. when executing the script from ALM , execution is not going to next statement and trying to execute the oBrowse object. Script is runnig from ALM however i am able to see that execution is not going to next statement of code. Using Siebel open UI application and having Siebel Open UI add-in under web add-in.